# CSS или Canvas, что лучше использовать для анимации? 2017 год

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

Что лучше использовать для анимации Flash, css или canvas?

**Flash** - все говорят "умирает". Для него рынок закрыли. На мобильном например, без специальных примочек вообще не запустить(с точки зрения пользователя, не программиста импортируемого air app).

**CSS** - работает. Но при рисовании всплывает куча левых багов, мельтешение достало. Да еще, разные браузеры по разному обрабатывают. Приходиться писать код для четырех разновидностей браузера сразу, что крайне неудобно.

**Canvas** - штука вроде как новая. Работает, но фактически только в гугл хроме? Проблема canvas в том, что нету никакого взаимодействия с UI. А рисовать формочки плюшечки и извращения, как то тяжеловато.

Вообщем прошу помощи у "старших". Подскажите пожалуйста который из них использовать когда нужна больше динамики ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если сложная графика ИМХО flash. Все проблемы баги 100 раз изучены.
На html5 всё по другому. И даже часто в библиотеках баги. Пишешь разработчикам, чтобы поправили и проходит чуть ли не полгода до фикса.

Если графика уровня тетриса - то можно и html5.

Answer (score 6):

Лучше находиться в реалиях решаемых задач.

Flash действительно уходит. Где то еще можно с ним поработать,если есть такая возможность, умеем лучше чем другое, почему бы и нет.

Цель html5 баннеры? Тут все так же зависит от критериев решаемой задачи. Например mail.ru, 150кб на анимированный html5 баннер - не всегда так просто, как кажется. Вот и решайте.. Вполне можно использовать как canvas так и css3 , главное все это впихнуть в критерии площадки\тз. Да и они наверно не дураки и показывать будут это аудитории, которая поддерживает эти технологии.
Да и на всякий просят сделать "заглушки")

Или речь про игровую анимацию. Что то простое в легкую на css с элементами дом. Сложнее лучше canvas. Это отличный инструмент и есть много [библиотек](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WebGL_frameworks) которые помогут не писать самому то, что хотелось бы из коробки. 
Да и работает он достаточно много где(так же есть полифилы), смотрим [тут например](https://caniuse.com/#search=canvas) (нажать show all)

Не забываем про плюшки в виде [webgl](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL) примеров [полно](http://webglsamples.org/)!

А дальше глубже: [asmjs](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asm.js),[WebAssemblу](http://webassembly.org/demo/).

Не забываем что помимо css, все не так гладко и в js. И поддерживать нужно то, что требуется)

Мое мнение - максимум из допустимого.

Comment: очень интересные показатели, не знал, что safari поддерживает больше всех новую технологию.